# Filling a class member data array using multiprocessing

Tags: python, arrays, class, multiprocessing

I have a class with an array of floats inside (it can be a np.array or even a python list, it does not really matter).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, RawArray
import numpy as np

class ClassTest:
    def __init__(self, a_N):
        self.N = a_N
        self.arr = np.zeros(a_N, float)
```

The array is not necessarily large but it can possibly be. Yet in order to fill every single element of `self.arr[i]`, a huge amount of work is needed, i.e. opening files, reading and parsing data, computing complicated functions, etc., thus, I would like to run it in parallel using either *threading* or *multiprocessing* modules. The former one is suffering from python global interpreter lock, basically running all the threads one by one instead of in parallel, and therefore does not provide any speed-up of the calculations. The latter seems to be suitable for the job, however, `self.arr` then needs to be shared among the processes somehow. I tried this code (both are methods of the class).

```
    def fillAll(self):
        Np = 4
        Nc = self.N//Np
        pool = Pool(processes=Np)
        for i in range(self.Np):
            i0 = i*Nc
            i1 = i0 + Nc
            pool.apply_async(self.fillChunk, (i0, i1, ))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def fillChunk(self, a_start, a_finish):
        for i in range(a_start, a_finish):
            self.arr[i] = computeOneCell(i)
```

where `computeOneCell(i)` is an external function that does all the work and returns a float. As far as I got from reading help in the Internet, this code will not work because every process will have its own copy of the class instance and all the actions done by forked processes won't affect the parent process. I also tried to use RawArray, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is used as shared memory. However, when I replace `self.arr = np.zeros(a_N, float)` to `self.arr_X = RawArray('d', a_N)` the code does not work. It does not crash but it does not go into `fillChunk` function either, as if `pool.apply_async(self.fillChunk, (i0, i1, ))` was never called.

I have a solution of this problem when no classes are involved, i.e. RawArray and pool are declared in the global scope, but I cannot figure out how to do it with classes.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to have multiple threads all making changes to the same array.  And you can't really have multiple processes doing that in a simple manner.

I would do something like

```
def fillAll(self):
    with Pool() as pool:
        for index, value in pool.imap(valueForCellAtIndex, range(self.N), chunksize=10):
            self.arr[index] = value

def valueForCellAtIndex(self, index):
    return index, computeOneCell(index)
```

You might even do slightly better by using `imap_unordered`.  By returning both the index and the value from `fillChunk`, you don't require the results be returned in order.

You may want to play around with `chunksize` to see what gives you the best results.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From the first glance the code you provided seems to work. However, I am even more puzzled now. For example, when you call `self.arr[index] = value`, is it a shared array for all the processes or is it a set of copies of the array somehow merged in the end to one?

Comment: The other processes never see the array.  The one-and-only array is in the main thread.  It asks the other threads what values go into each index, but only the main thread has the actual array so that it can store the values.  All `fillCell` knows is that it is supposed to provide a value given an index--I probably shouldn't have named the function `fillCell` but `valueForIndex` instead since it doesn't actually fill the cell.  (I'm editing the code since I think that's a little clearer.)

Comment: It makes much sense now! But what is we need to have an array shared by processes, for example, if the `fillCell` method needs to know something about neighboring cells in the array. Basically, I am trying to figure out a general structure of a parallelized program on shared memory wrapped in class methods, something similar to what we can do with POSIX threads in C/C++.

Comment: You might want to look at `multiprocessing.Value` and `multiprocessing.Array` which allow you to share memory across processes.  Note that sharing memory across threads and processes is extremely error prone and it's too easy to write incorrect code and race conditions.  That's why I was purposely avoiding it above.